# Return object from function with keys based on a property of the input object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a function that receives an object with certain properties, then use one of those properties in order to generate the types of the result.

function params

```js
interface Params<T> {
  entries?: { [key in T['entries']: string]: number }
  unit?: string
}
```

and the result

```js
type Result<T> = { [key in T: string]: string }
```

where T in the result is `Params['entries']`

I setup a simple [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&esModuleInterop=false&target=99&ssl=33&ssc=8&pln=33&pc=1#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) to display my attempt.

At the moment, if you type `result.` it only suggests `big|small` which are the default values, and not `a` which was the actual object input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
generateUnitStrings = <O>(options?: Params<O>) // ---> the <O>
```

What is O? That's why `PickEntries<O> extends never` returns true. One way to check is doing this

```
const result = generateUnitStrings<{ entries: { a: number } }>({ entries: { a: 1 } })
```

And you'll see that it actually works. autocompletion correctly suggests 'a'. The reason is when you call `generateUnitStrings`, `O` correctly gets switched with `{ entries: { a: number } }` and passes it to Params and everything works.

Try this (it looks a little bit weird to me, but it actually works!):

```
export const generateUnitStrings = <O extends Params<O>>(options?: O) => {
...
```

---

EDIT

> Yes, but now your solution only suggests something if generateUnitStrings() has parameters, if it used empty as generateUnitStrings() it doesn't auto-suggests the default parameters small|big

Providing a default generic type (in this case typeof defaultParams) seems to get the job done

```
export const generateUnitStrings = <O extends Params<O> = typeof defaultParams>(options?: O) => {
  const entries = (options && options.entries) || defaultParams.entries
  const unit = (options && options.unit) || defaultParams.unit

  return Object.keys(entries).reduce(
    (acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v]: `${entries[v as keyof typeof entries]}${unit}` }),
    {}
  ) as PickEntries<O> extends never ? Result<PickEntries<typeof defaultParams>> : Result<PickEntries<O>>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&esModuleInterop=false&target=99&ssl=1&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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)

Your initial code for reference

```
type FilterProperties<T, P> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends P ? K : never
}[keyof T]
type PickEntries<T> = T[FilterProperties<T, 'entries'>]

interface Params<T> {
  entries?: { [K in keyof PickEntries<T>]: number }
  unit?: string
}

type Result<T> = { [P in keyof T]: string }

export const defaultParams = {
  entries: {
    small: 600,
    big: 1200,
  },
  unit: 'px',
}

export const generateUnitStrings = <O>(options?: Params<O>) => {
  const entries = (options && options.entries) || defaultParams.entries
  const unit = (options && options.unit) || defaultParams.unit

  return Object.keys(entries).reduce(
    (acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v]: `${entries[v as keyof typeof entries]}${unit}` }),
    {}
  ) as PickEntries<O> extends never ? Result<PickEntries<typeof defaultParams>> : Result<PickEntries<O>>
}

const result = generateUnitStrings({ entries: { a: 1 } })
```

Comment: Yes, but now your solution only suggests something if `generateUnitStrings()` has parameters, if it used empty as `generateUnitStrings()` it doesn't auto-suggests the default parameters `small|big`

Comment: @JCQuintas you have to change `PickEntries<O> extends never ?`

Comment: @JCQuintas for example `O extends unknown ?`

Comment: @JCQuintas no that won't work.. I'm trying to find a solution

Comment: @JCQuintas try this `export const generateUnitStrings = <O extends Params<O> = typeof defaultParams>(options?: O) => {`

Comment: NICE! It works. Thank you so much :)
I've been trying to find a solution for this for like 8 hours